# Show that there exists sets $A, B$ in $R$ such that $(A \cup B)^o \neq A^0 \cup B^o$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$\newcommand{\closure}{\operatorname{closure}}$ Show that there exists sets $A, B$ in $R$ such that

1) $(A \cup B)^\circ \neq A^\circ \cup B^\circ$

and

$2)$  $\operatorname{closure}(A \cap  B) \neq  \closure A \cap \closure B$

attempt for 1)

Suppose $A = [-3,2]$, $B = [1,4]$.

Then $A \cup B = [1,2]$.

And $ A^\circ = (-3,2), B^\circ = (1,4)$

Thus $A^\circ \cup B^\circ = (1,2)$
Thus they are not equal.

Is part 1) fine?

can someone please help me with a counterexample for part 2)? I am having trouble with the closure.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not fine.  $A\cup B$ is the union of the intervals, not their intersection.

$$A\cup B = [-3;2]\cup[1;4] = [-3; 4]
\\[1ex]
A\cap B = [-3;2]\cap[1;4] = [1; 2]
$$

---

**Hint:** If $(A\cup B)^\circ\neq A^\circ\cup B^\circ$ then you need to select two sets so that there exists some element that is in the interior of the union but not in the union of the interiors.

$$\exists x \;\Big(x\in (A\cup B)^\circ \;\wedge\; x\notin A^\circ \cup B^\circ\Big)$$

Comment: your are right. So the the interior for $A \cup B = [-3,4]$ and the interior of the union of each set would be $(-3,4)$. Thus not equal?

Comment: @user39492 Nope.  The interior of the union is $(-3;4)$ and the union of the interiors is $(-3;4)$, so they are equal.  Goldilocks says "Oh, dear.  These sets overlap *too* much."  Can you get it *just right*?

Comment: How far have you come, now, @user39492 ?